# Use CSS to maintain height of web app = innerHeight

Tags: html, ios, css

I'm building a responsive web app and want to guarantee that nothing is unintentionally hidden by the address bar or navigation bar in iOS Safari and other mobile browsers.

[image]

I'm currently using this code:

```
        window.onresize = function (event) {
            toastr.warning("resized");
            var h = window.innerHeight;
            document.getElementById("applicationHost").style.height = h + 'px';
        };
```

But I was wondering if there's a CSS-only way to solve this problem.

Comment: `height:100%` on the `html, body, #applicationHost`..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "vh" units would help in this case, hard to tell without seeing code and doing some testing. Try adding `height:100vh;` to the element that needs to have the viewport height.